# Sails.js with Socket.io: Blasting events works fine, but broadcasting doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

In my frontend I'm using the `sails.io.js` wrapper. I'm trying to connect to my backend and listen for notifications. This works fine when I'm using blast to send out to all connected sockets, but broadcasting does nothing.
However, joining a room seems to work as the callback from the `join` function gets executed without any errors.

**The frontend part:**

```
import * as socketIoClient from 'socket.io-client'
import * as sailsIo from 'sails.io.js'

const io = sailsIo(socketIoClient)
io.sails.url = 'localhost:1337'
io.sails.environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
io.sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie = false

  io.socket.get('/notification/join', (data, jwRes) => {
    console.log('Server responded with status code ' + jwRes.statusCode + ' and data: ', data);
  })
  io.socket.on('notification', data => {
    console.log('Server says: ', data);
  })
```

**My Sails Controller:**

```
export const join = async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.isSocket) {
    return res.badRequest();
  }
  // Join a user specific notification room
  sails.sockets.join(req, 'notification', error => {
    if (!error) console.log('Everything went fine')
     return res.send('Connected') // this works so far
  })

  // Send events each second
  setInterval(() => {
    sails.sockets.broadcast('notification', { data: 'Real notification' }) // This never works
    sails.sockets.blast('notification', {data: 'BLAST'}) // This works perfectly
  }, 1000)
}
```

Any suggestion on what goes wrong? Like I said, the callback of joining the room gets executed without an error, also the blast call works fine and the frontend is able to receive the message.

Comment: Are you trying to use `notification` as an event name or a room name ? Because `blast` is expecting an event name while `broadcast` is expecting an event name and a room name.

See: [blast](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets/blast) and [broadcast](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets/broadcast)

Comment: @BrahmaDev I feel bad for overlooking this. Looks promising, I'll test it out tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: @BrahmaDev I can confirm now that solved the issue. Thank you very much.